# Multi-field Search with Array Using 'AND' Operator in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query the values of a multi-value field as separate 'fields' in the same way I'm querying the other fields.
I have a data structure like so:

```
{
  name: 'foo one',
  alternate_name: 'bar two',
  lay_name: 'baz three',
  tags: ['stuff like', 'this that']
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
{
  query:
    query: stuff
    type: 'best_fields',
    fields: ['name', 'alternate_name', 'lay_name', 'tags'],
    operator: 'and'
}
```

The 'type' and 'operator' work perfectly for the single value fields in only matching when the value contains my entire query. For example, querying 'foo two' doesn't return a match.

I'd like the tags field to behave the same way. Right now, querying 'stuff that' will return a match when it shouldn't because no fields or tag values contain both words in a single value. Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
Val's assessment was spot on. I've updated my mapping to the following (using [elasticsearch-rails](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails)/[elasticsearch-model](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)):

```
mapping dynamic: false, include_in_all: true do
  ... other fields ...
  indexes :tags, type: 'nested' do
    indexes :tag, type: 'string', include_in_parent: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please show your mapping type, but I suspect your `tags` field is a simple `string` field like this:

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "tags" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case ES will "flatten" all your tags under the hood in the `tags` field at indexing time like this:

```
tags: "stuff", "like", "this", "that"
```

i.e. this is why you get results when querying "stuff that", because the `tags` field contains both words.

The way forward would be to make `tags` a [nested object type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html), like this

```
{
    "your_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "tags" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "tag" : {"type": "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to reindex your data but at least querying for `tags: "stuff that"` will not return anything anymore. Your tag tokens will be "kept together" as you expect. Give it a try.

Comment: You were spot on. Thank you!