# elasticsearch: or operator, number of matches

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to score my searches according to the number of matches when using operator "or"?

Currently query looks like this:

```
"query": {
  "function_score": {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "tags.eng": {
        "query": "apples banana juice",
        "operator": "or",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
        }
      }
    },
    "script_score": {
      "script": # TODO
    },
    "boost_mode": "replace" 
  }
}
```

I don't want to use "and" operator, since I want documents containing "apple juice" to be found, as well as documents containing only "juice", etc. However a document containing the three words should score more than documents containing two words or a single word, and so on.

I found a possible solution here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13806
which uses bool queries. However I don't know how to access the tokens (in this example: apples, banana, juice) generated by the analyzer.

Any help?

Comment: I think what you're trying to do is to create your own search algorithm. In general your premise should work. But what if the document has 5 times apple, or there's only one document that has apple in it, surely that is more of a relevant answer than all the other documents that have banana? Or... you catch my drift :) BM25 is how this relevancy is now calculated. You can have a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html for fine tuning this process or come up with your own.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn’t mention before, but I am not searching texts. I’m searching previously tagged docs and frequencies are not important. I try to clarify with another example. Suppose I’m searching for “blue sky” and I have 4 docs tagged with: [sky, moon], [blue car, blue jeans, city], [blue sea, sky, surf], [blue sky, village]. I want the 3rd to be more relevant than the 1st and 2nd, but less then the 4th. I currently have a bool query using “and”, and another using “or”, so I can distinguish the 4th case from the others, but I can’t distinguish the 3rd from the 1st and 2nd.

Comment: If you haven't read this already, i'd like to point you to this:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ignoring-tfidf.html

Comment: You're looking at this from a semantic standpoint but ES only sees bits and bytes. `blue sea` and `blue` might look similar to you and me but for ES it's completely different. If you want docs tagged with `blue sky` also to come up in searches for `blue`, you should add the 'blue' tag.

Comment: Thank you @archit. I new already the link you pointed too, and it actually look helpful. However, in that example a query is required for each search term ("wifi", "garden", "pool"). In my particular case I want to search for terms with more than one word, like "blue sky", and match the full term as well as the individual words, i.e., the tokens "blue" and "sky", generated by an analyzer. My issue is: it is possible to access these tokens inside the query? Otherwise, what would you suggest?

Comment: @renata Try out the gist and let me know if there are any problems with it:
https://gist.github.com/archit12/9e240ec5deed65413dea9841f3f61ce1

Comment: @archit, thx a lot for your support. I have elasticsearch 6.1. I get the following error when running the query: "[constant_score] query does not support [query]". Could it be that constant_score only supports "filter"? I replaced "constant_score" with "function_score" and it works, but only retrieves the first document (which has "tags": "blue sky red")

Comment: Oh, i tried it on ES 2.3. Let me check with 6.

Comment: Could you also try it once with query replaced with filter inside constant_score? I've corrected the gist too.
https://gist.github.com/archit12/9e240ec5deed65413dea9841f3f61ce1

Comment: Thx again! I tried the code from your new gist. constant_score works with filter, however no scores are computed in the filter context, as explain [here] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html). Therefore your example query "blue red" returns documents that matches either "blue" or "red", but I still need to know how good are the matches, i.e., "blue sky red" should score higher than "blue sky" and "red sky".

Comment: Based on your idea of having a somewhat constant score I defined a custom similarity that simply returns 1. See gist: https://gist.github.com/renatalucia/80f04d7f03d22a9d65453c630e463839 It works almost as I want, except that a search for "blue red sky" returns both ["blue sky red"] and ["blue sky", "blue red"] with the same score, but the first should score higher than the second. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, if that's the case with the same index settings as in my gist, how does this work: 
`GET renata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tags": "blue red"
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussions above I came up with the following solution, which is a bit different that I imagined when I asked the question, but works for my case.

First of all I defined a new similarity:

```
"settings": {
        "similarity": {
            "boost_similarity": {
                "type": "scripted",
                "script": {
                    "source": "return 1;"
                }
            }
        }
...
}
```

Then I had the following problem:
a query for "apple banana juice" had the same score for a doc with tags ["apple juice", "apple"] and another doc with tag ["banana", "apple juice"]. Although I would like to score the second one higher. 
From the [this other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30361028/multi-field-search-with-array-using-and-operator-in-elasticsearch) I found out that this issue was caused because I had a nested field. And I created a usual text field to address it.

But I also was wanted to distinguish between a doc with tags ["apple", "banana", "juice"] and another doc with tag ["apple banana juice"] (all three words in the same tag). The final solution was therefore to keep both fields (a nested and a text field) for my tags.

Finally the query consists of bool query with two should clauses: the first should clause is performed on the text field and uses an "or" operator. The second should clause is performed on the nested field and uses and "and operator"

Despite I found a solution for this specific issue, I still face a few other problems when using ES to search for tagged documents. The examples in the documentation seem to work very well when searching for full texts. But does someone know where I can find something more specific to  tagged documents?